# Make automatic login to website via script

Tags: javascript, autologin

I have a batch file which has user name and password to login a website in below format on line number 16.5th word in the line is username and 7th word is the password.

**start VPNGUI  -c -user 1000 -pwd 123456**

I need a help on JavaScript which should open the homepage of website,read the batch file to collect username and password ,auto fill the username and password on the home page and login using send keys.
I have tried using vbscript ,below is my code but i need this in Java which should allow the user auto login to the web site on a single click.

**VBScript:-**

```
Dim username
Dim password
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Autoconnect\connect.bat", ForReading)

For i = 1 to 15
    objTextFile.ReadLine
Next

strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
segments = Split(strLine," ")
username = segments(5)
pwd = Split(strLine," ")
password= pwd(7)

objTextFile.Close

set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
call WshShell.Run("https://mywebsite.com", 1, false) 'This will open your default browser

WScript.Sleep 5000
WshShell.SendKeys username 
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys password
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Quit()
```

Can anyone suggest me how can i achieve this using Java Script.

Sami.

Answer (score 1):

If you want JavaScript on a website such that it logs in to another website with one click, that is not possible because you cannot submit forms cross-domain.

Comment: Thanks @Bemmu for your response.Can you please suggest me a way.